# How to draw a polyline by (XYZ) coordinates using OpenGL and Python

Tags: python, 3d, pyqtgraph

I need to draw a 3D polyline using OpenGl for Python based on (X,Y,Z) coordinates. Instead of numpy linespace (something like this):

```
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
import numpy as np

w = gl.GLViewWidget()

y = np.linspace(1,3,3)
x = np.linspace(1,3,3)
pts = (x,y) 
sh1 = gl.GLLinePlotItem(pos=pts, width=1, antialias=False)
w.addItem(sh1)
```

I want to have something more straightforward where I'll be able to define line coordinate as actual (starting and ending point coordinates) for a line.
More like this (**pseudo-code**):

```
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
import numpy as np

w = gl.GLViewWidget()

xx = 10
yx = 11
zx = 10

xy = 20
yy = 21
zy = 20

Xdot = (xx,yx,zx)
Ydot = (xy,yy,zy)
pts = (Xdot,Ydot) 
sh1 = gl.GLLinePlotItem(pos=pts, width=1, antialias=False)
w.addItem(sh1)
```

So, here I'm showing starting and ending point for a line in 3D space. But obviously, it doesn't work, how to implement this in such way as it described at pseudocode correctly?

[image: example]

Comment: `pts = np.array([Xdot, Ydot])`, you have to look around to see that, your camera looks at (0,0,0) by default

Comment: @Jonas SUPER HIGHLY Appreciated, That's exactly what I need.    Just one more quick question: How to lock camera at the different position?

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: @Jonas Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed the coordinates so you see the line from the start.
I also added the `QApplication`, so that its stand-alone.

```
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtWidgets
import numpy as np
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = gl.GLViewWidget()

    xx = 0
    yx = 0
    zx = 0

    xy = 1
    yy = 0
    zy = 0

    Xdot = (xx, yx, zx)
    Ydot = (xy, yy, zy)

    pts = np.array([Xdot, Ydot])
    sh1 = gl.GLLinePlotItem(pos=pts, width=1, antialias=False)
    w.addItem(sh1)
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

You can add more segments by

```
    Zdot = (1, 1, 1)
    pts = np.array([Xdot, Ydot, Zdot])
```

To set the center (point which the camera rotates around):

```
    from pyqtgraph import Vector
    w.opts['center'] = Vector(0,0,10)
```

To set the position (relative to that center, elevation and azimuth are angles in degree):

```
    w.setCameraPosition(distance=10, elevation=42, azimuth=42)
```

To lock the position you should inherit from GLViewWidget and overload `mouseMoveEvent` and `wheelEvent`. The dirty way is like this:

```
def empty(ev):
    return None
w.mouseMoveEvent = empty
w.wheelEvent = empty
```

You define an empty function and set your mouse input events to that function.